# Adding Datagridview rows from one grid to another

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have two forms Form1(DGV1) and Form2(DGV2) with Datagridview control on both the forms.

On Form1 there is a button link to Form2 where user can add rows to Form1 datagridview(DGV1)
..In Form2 Datagridview there is a checkbox in the first column and the user can select only one row at a time.So there are two button on Form2 1) Done 2) Add Items

When user clicks on Add Items by selecting the rows one after another the rows must be added to the datagridview on Form1 and when Done button is clicked Form 1 should be displayed with all the rows that are added.

```
int index = objQM.gvItemDetails.Rows.Add();
int Sno = index + 1;
string Desc = gvInventory.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
int Sellqty = LoadSellQty();
 decimal UnitCost = Convert.ToDecimal(gvInventory.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[8].Value.ToString());
 decimal Amount = LoadSellQty() * UnitCost;
 objQM.gvItemDetails.Rows.Insert(index,false, Sno, Desc, Sellqty, UnitCost, Amount);
```

I am able to add one row into Form1 datagridview but when the second row is added the row which was added earlier is lost.

Can you please suggest a way to solve this.

Thank you.

Comment: Just to clarify: `objQM.gvItemDetails` is DGV1 and `gvInventory` is DGV2? At once you can add only one row (the selected one ("In Form2 Datagridview there is a checkbox in the first column and the user can select only one row at a time.")? Is this all code that is handling row adding?

Comment: Yeah you are right .. gvItemDetails is the parent grid and gvInventory is the child grid.First I am checking whether the checkbox is checked in the gvInventory grid. if (Convert.ToBoolean(gvInventory.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[0].FormattedValue))
            {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding for each row selected in `gvInventory` two rows in parent grid (is that wanted way of working?), if not try this:

```
int index = objQM.gvItemDetails.Rows.Add();
DataGridViewRow row = objQM.gvItemDetails.Rows[index]; //here you get a reference to added row
row.Cells[0] = false;
row.Cells[1] = index + 1; //old Sno
row.Cells[2] = gvInventory.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
row.Cells[3] = LoadSellQty();
row.Cells[4] = Convert.ToDecimal(gvInventory.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[8].Value.ToString());
row.Cells[5] = LoadSellQty() * UnitCost;
```

This way you add new row and fill it with values. From code you gave it is not clear why first row is lost, so maybe I will need some more information.

Comment: Yeah I have noticed it is adding two rows in Parent grid.thanks.When I am trying to add the datagridview row to gvItemDetails as below objQM.gvItemDetails.Rows.Add(row); it throws an error it belongs to datagridview control.Can you please help me where am I going wrong

Comment: Because you are trying to add it again! :) This line `int index = objQM.gvItemDetails.Rows.Add();` adds new row and return its index, next lines are filling data in and that is it :).

Comment: I have changed the code as objQM.gvItemDetails.Rows[index].Clone() and it works Cool.But the problem is an additional row is created.So how can I avoid it.

Comment: As you have mentioned the line int index = objQM.gvItemDetails.Rows.Add(); is creating an additional dummy row.Any alternative for that.

Comment: Hi gzaxx...I have made a small change in the code and works great.I have added this line objQM.gvItemDetails.Rows.Add();               without the int index and created a static variable int index and increased its value while inserting.Thanks man.

Comment: Hi gzaxx.. it works fine but if I add 2 rows it display the first 2 rows along with 2 dummy rows.If I add 3 rows it also display 3 dummy rows after inserting the selected rows.Can you please help me with dat.

Comment: static int index = 0;
private void LoadItemDetailsforQuotations()
{     if (Convert.ToBoolean(gvInventory.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[0].FormattedValue)){         
 objQM.gvItemDetails.Rows.Add();                
DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)objQM.gvItemDetails.Rows[index].Clone();
decimal UnitCost = Convert.ToDecimal(gvInventory.Rows.RowIndex].Cells[8].Value.ToString());
 row.Cells[0].Value = false; row.Cells[1].Value =index+ 1;
row.Cells[2].Value = gvInventory.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[6].Value.ToString();row.Cells[3].Value = LoadSellQty();

Comment: row.Cells[4].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(gvInventory.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[8].Value.ToString());
                row.Cells[5].Value = LoadSellQty() * UnitCost;
                objQM.gvItemDetails.Rows.Insert(index,row);
                index++;

Comment: Remove this line: `objQM.gvItemDetails.Rows.Add();` it is no longer needed.

Comment: Awesome. I thought I need to add this line of code objQM.gvItemDetails.Insert(index,row) and it throws some other error. Now everything is fine dude.Works great.

Comment: Hi Dude...How can I filter a datagridview when there is no datatable..as this is the case in my scenerio.